# Angular & Spring security - Secure folders and files

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

**Hello**,

I successfully set up an angular webapp with spring security following this tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Everything works fine and I additionally configured spring security to use MySql database.

I am using spring boot and so my angularJS files are located in the static folder:

- "src/main/resources/static/js"
- "src/main/resources/static/css"
- ...

**My first question** is about the spring security configuration and which files/folders from the angular webapp I have to secure?
Do I have to permit access to all the static content in spring security configuration? e.g.:

```
http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/").permitAll()
```

Or is this not a good idea? What is best practice here?
I first tried to give access to only the the "/" and "/login" page, but this does not worked for me!

Example spring security configuration from the tutorial:

```
  @Configuration
  @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
  protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .httpBasic()
      .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
  }
```

**My second question** is about the angular file- and folder-structure under /static in my spring boot app. How can I configure an individual folder for my angular webapp in spring boot and give the app access with spring security, e.g. with this structure (not under /static):

```
MyAngularApp
  -- login
     -- Controller
        -- loginController
     -- Services
     -- Templates
        -- login.html
  -- Feature 2
     -- Controller
     -- Services
     -- Templates
  -- Feature 3
     -- Controller
     -- Services
     -- Templates
```

And what does the spring security configuration should look like for this structure?

Comment: Securing controllers etc. separately would only work, if you use them on different pages (different HTML pages). If you have a true SPA, that won't work.

Comment: So it`s ok, if I give access to all angular files:  /js/** and /css/** ?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the static resources for spring MVC as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("(/resources/");    
    }
}
```

[Please refer this for more details.](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) and [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources)

Comment: Ok, so I have to define a new ressource "MyAngularApp" like this?

        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/MyAngularApp/**")
          .addResourceLocations("(/MyAngularApp/");    

Is my app then accesssible at src/main/MyAngularApp/ ?